# Symfony error with controller and namespace

Tags: symfony

I'm trying a school project in Symfony but I'm getting an error that stopped me for several hours, I couldn't find any answer so I hope someone of you can help me.

I'm trying to set a view for a user registration with a form, I've follow some Symfony cookbook guides but couldn't reach to the end.

I'll put you on situation, I have a bundle with the default controller where I have put by now all functions that render a view, but I want to do it better and to have various controllers to have a better organization.

I've created a controller called:
**AccountControler.php**
which is in
**// src/AppBundle/Controller/AccountController.php**

```
     <?php
    // src/AppBundle/Controller/AccountController.php
    namespace AdrianG\RegisterBundle\Controller;
    
    
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use AdrianG\RegisterBundle\Form\UserType;
    use AdrianG\RegisterBundle\Entity\User;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    
    class RegistrationController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/register", name="user_registration")
         */
        public function registerAction(Request $request)
        {
//....
```

I think the routing is correct:

```
user_registration:
    pattern:  /register
    defaults: { _controller: AdrianGRegisterBundle:Account:register}
```

and I'm getting an error when trying to access

**localhost/symfony8/web/app_dev.php/user/register**

The autoloader expected class "AdrianG\RegisterBundle\Controller\AccountController" to be defined in file "/Applications/AMPPS/www/symfony8/src/AdrianG/RegisterBundle/Controller/AccountController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

I'm able to access to anywhere  with my routes and with DefaultController.php
I 've search and people says about namespace ( ¿I think its correct no? ) or about <? that should be <?php

I really don't know what can be the problem and some help would be really nice

**EDIT:** DefaultController.php and AccountControler.php are in the same folder, and they have the same namespace, should it be so?

Comment: The file is called AccountController.php, but the class inside it is called RegistrationController. You should follow PSR-4 and name the class too: "AccountController"

Comment: okok, ill try that solution, what a fast response
( i just copied the names from the symfony cookbook)
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html#handling-the-form-submission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got your routing wrong.
It should be;

```
user_registration:
    pattern:  /register
    defaults: { _controller: AdrianGRegisterBundle:Registration:register}
```

The filename of the class should also be `RegistrationController.php`

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks, thanks to both of you, i think that symfony should correct it from his page

Comment: Which page were you following?  You have the route defined in a routing file as well as an annotation.  I suspect you are mixing up two different pieces of documentation.

Comment: this one
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html#handling-the-form-submission
Im for sure mixing  different pieces of documentation, i think somewhere in the documentation said that i can use one of them, just to many copy/paste and I forgot to delte that because im used to see those lines as commentarys, not as programing code, thanks for the "tip"